# Reshaping a data.frame with additional rows based on multiple items regexed from a single column

Tags: r

I have a datatable containing a list of tweets grabbed using the twitteR library and want get a list of tweets annotated with

So for example, I start with:

```
tmp=data.frame(tweets=c("this tweet with #onehashtag","#two hashtags #here","no hashtags"),dummy=c('random','other','column'))
> tmp
                       tweets  dummy
1 this tweet with #onehashtag random
2         #two hashtags #here  other
3                 no hashtags column
```

and would like to generate:

```
result=data.frame(tweets=c("this tweet with #onehashtag","#two hashtags #here","#two hashtags #here","no hashtags"),dummy=c('random','other','other','column'),tag=c('#onehashtag','#two','#here',NA))
> result
                       tweets  dummy        tag
1 this tweet with #onehashtag random #onehashtag
2         #two hashtags #here  other        #two
3         #two hashtags #here  other       #here
4                 no hashtags column        <NA>
```

I can use the regular expression:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("#two hashtags #here","#[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

to extract the tags from a tweet into a list, maybe using something like:

```
tmp$tags=sapply(tmp$tweets,function(x) str_extract_all(x,'#[a-zA-Z0-9]+'))
> tmp
                       tweets  dummy        tags
1 this tweet with #onehashtag random #onehashtag
2         #two hashtags #here  other #two, #here
3                 no hashtags column
```

but I'm missing a trick somewhere and can't see how to use this as the basis for creating the duplicate rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour for rows with and without tags differs, so your code will be easier to understand if you treat those cases separately.

Use `str_extract_all` as before to get the tags.

```
tags <- str_extract_all(tmp$tweets, '#[a-zA-Z0-9]+')
```

(You can also use the regex shortcut alnum to get all alphanumeric characters.  `'#[[:alnum:]]+'`.)

Use `rep` to find out how many times to repeat each row.

```
index <- rep.int(seq_len(nrow(tmp)), sapply(tags, length))
```

Expand `tmp` using this index, and add a tag column.

```
tagged <- tmp[index, ]
tagged$tags <- unlist(tags)
```

Rows with no tags should appear once (not zero times) and have NA in the tag column.

```
has_no_tag <- sapply(tags, function(x) length(x) == 0L)
not_tagged <- tmp[has_no_tag, ]
not_tagged$tags <- NA
```

Combine the two.

```
all_data <- rbind(tagged, not_tagged)
```

Answer (score 1):

First lets get the matches:

```
matches <- gregexpr("#[a-zA-Z0-9]+",tmp$tweets)
matches
[[1]]
[1] 17
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1]  1 15
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
```

Now we can use this to get the correct number of rows from the original `data.frame`:

```
rep(seq(matches),times=sapply(matches,length))
[1] 1 2 2 3
tmp2 <- tmp[rep(seq(matches),times=sapply(matches,length)),]
```

Now use the matches to get the start and end positions:

```
starts <- unlist(matches)
ends <- starts + unlist(sapply(matches,function(x) attr(x,"match.length"))) - 1
```

And use `substr` to extract:

```
tmp2$tag <- substr(tmp2$tweets,starts,ends)
tmp2
                         tweets  dummy         tag
1   this tweet with #onehashtag random #onehashtag
2           #two hashtags #here  other        #two
2.1         #two hashtags #here  other       #here
3                   no hashtags column
```